# Running makefile based C project in Xcode 6 on OS X 10.9

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I have a C project that uses a Makefile to compile so, basically I tell Xcode to rely on an external build tool (make).

Since I updated from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6, I am not able to Run that project (build still works). Each time I try to run the execute I get the following error message :

> My Mac runs OS X 10.9.5, which is lower than project's minimum
>   deployment target. Change your project's minimum deployment target or
>   upgrade My Mac's to version of OS X.

I configured the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 10.9, and that did not change anything.

So, since I would like keep 10.9 for now, is there a way to tell Xcode that my project can run on 10.9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just deleted and recreated the target and that solved the issue...